# How can I pass arguments to a python script being fed to the interpreter on stdin?

Tags: python

I have a bash script which exports two auxiliary python scripts, using heredoc with " ", and executes them from /tmp.

It works fine, but when i deployed this script on a server which has automatic /tmp cleanup, it will always delete the exported python scripts after a while.

Moreover, I can not manually copy the needed python scripts to the server, only this script executes.

an idea came to me

Right now I export the scripts like this

```
cat << "SCRIPT" > /tmp/script.py && chmod +x /tmp/script.py
```

And then execute them with an argument

I tried doing it like this

```
python << "SCRIPT"
```

The script runs, but it doesn't take arguemnts. I tried quoting and using xargs.

Is there any way to pass arguments to scripts executed like this?

Comment: `python arg1 arg2 <<SCRIPT` passes arguments `arg1` and `arg2` to `python` just fine. How to make the interpreter run your Python script from stdin with the arguments on the command line is a question about Python, not about bash.

Comment: _Personally_, though, I don't do it that way in the first place. `python -c "$script" args...` is my preferred approach; that way `python` can still read input from stdin.

Comment: It would make this a stronger question if you included examples of _how_ you're trying to pass arguments to your script. You say you "tried quoting and using xargs", but that doesn't show us the exact quoting, or the exact use of xargs.

Comment: ...and to be clear: This can be different for different scripting languages; there's no guarantee that what works for Python will work elsewhere. For example, with bash, you need to pass it an argument `-s` to inform it that future arguments are for the script being passed on stdin and not for the interpreter itself.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy So the better was is to run the python scripts from a variable? How can I put heredoc in a variable?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The python scripts i need to run have about 4-5 arguments, that's where the quotes went, i tried declaring the "python from heredoc" as a function

Comment: eh, I wouldn't say _universally_ better, but _often_ better. `pyscript=$(cat <<'EOF'`, your text, then a line with only `EOF`, then `)`; then `python -c "$pyscript" arg1 arg2 arg3` -- that way you can pipe to your Python interpreter, or it can prompt on stdin, or so forth.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you, that worked perfectly. Never knew of python -c

Comment: If the answer solved your question, click the checkmark next to it to mark the question solved. I'll edit `python -c` in so that's covered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass the Python interpreter `-` as the filename you want it to read code from, when you want it to get code from stdin. Thus:

```sh
python - "argument one" "argument two" "argument three" <<'EOF'
import sys, pprint
pprint.pprint(sys.argv)
EOF
```

...properly emits:

```
['-', 'argument one', 'argument two', 'argument three']
```

---

Another way to pass code into a Python interpreter is on the command line:

```sh
pyscript=$(cat <<'EOF'
import sys, pprint
pprint.pprint(sys.argv)
EOF
)

python -c "$pyscript" "argument one" "argument two" "argument three"
```

...which will have slightly different output:

```
['-c', 'argument one', 'argument two', 'argument three']
```